# Shortest path C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, shortest-path

Iam trying to do a program which gives us shortest path on a map(map is a picture which has Rectangle on it. and my turn points are Rectangle's edge points. can anybody help me to find shortest path on this points?[image: Red dots are my point which ı must find shortest path in it]

As you can see ı have begin point and an end point. ımust start from begin to end and path must be from point. path can not be on Rectangle because it is my wall so ı cant go in or over it.
So can any body help???

Comment: what point's can you use?

Comment: There's a whole set of algorithms for this problem. You should be a bit more specific of where you're having a problem. I don't think you will find anybody to write the solution for you here.

Comment: look into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm you just need to define the points you can use.

Comment: I already answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238267/how-do-you-implement-a-program-to-find-the-shortest-path-in-a-2d-plane/13239796#13239796

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If efficiency is not an issue and a simple solution is OK, you could consider the following pseudo-code:

```
visited = new bool[N,M]
points = new List<Point>()
prev = new List<int>() 
points.Add(Begin)
prev.Add(-1)
visited[Begin.X, Begin.Y] = true

for(i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
    p = points(i)
    foreach neighbor of p
        if neighbor is not wall && !visited[neighbor.X, neighbor.Y]
            points.Add(neighbor)
            prev.Add(i)
            visited[neighbor.X, neighbor.Y] = true
            if neighbor == End
                 // we are done, print path (without Begin and End)
                 j = i
                 while j != 0
                     print points[j]
                     j = prev[j]
                 return
// no solution found
```

(It is just a modification of Flood fill algorithm, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill.)